# MonoDevelop - Remove SVN Source Control

Tags: svn, version-control, monodevelop

I have a project which is attached to a SVN provider. I wish to move it to another repository, but when I try to publish to this new location, I am told the project is already bound to another. How do I break the link to that provider?

MonoDevelop 2.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just delete all of the .SVN files/folders from the project directory structure.

Answer (score 10):

You can also do a SVN Export, which will export all the file/folder in an external folder without the .svn folders/files.

Answer (score 3):

(Disclaimer: I don't know anything about MonoDevelop, but SVN) Did you try removing all the .svn directories (using system shell). That would remove the SVN ties. Make sure to back up your project/solution first ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure about MonoDevelop specifics, but a project is a "svn working copy" when it contains `.svn` directories, one each per actual directory in the project. If you remove these, then it will no longer be tied to a Subversion server.